# return JSON payload and byte response

Tags: python, fastapi

I have REST endpoint that returns

```
{
    "dataset": [
        {
            "name": "file1",
            "location": "https://container/file1.csv"
        },
        {
            "name": "file2",
            "location": "https://container/file2.csv"
        }
    ]
}
```

I return it as a pydantic model that looks like this

```
class ResponseBodySuccessDataset(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(description="Name of the generated data object")
    location: HttpUrl = Field(
        description="URL of generated data object as returned to requestor",
    )


class DummyDataResponseBodySuccess(BaseModel):
    dataset: list[ResponseBodySuccessDataset] = Field(
        description="Dataset array as returned to requestor",
    )
```

However aside returning JSON payload, I also want to return an archive of all the files in the dataset.

I tried using `Response`

```
 return Response(content=zip_stream.getvalue(), media_type="application/zip", headers=dummy_datasets[0])
```

by zipping all the files and passing dataset as a header (I use only the first element as it requires additional key to make the whole response as a dictionary).

However I want also to have the JSON payload in the response. Is there a way to achive?